# Why does github console show only one changed file, but git diff shows several?

Tags: git, github

When I view the commit on github it shows only one file changed.  However, doing `git diff` between that commit and the commit directly before it, it shows several changed files.  How is this possible?

Comment: Try `git add -uv`. What is the operating system and are the files actually being updates on your git server?

Comment: You should show us the command and, if possible the github page.

Comment: Is the commit multiple lines long? In that case, first line is shown and treated as title, and rest as description and hidden by default.